# LangChain LCEL chain construction - unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'NoneType'

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I'm trying to construct a chain with LCEL, and I'm getting this exception even though I've verified that `table_summarization`, `all_keywords`, and `all_keywords_string` are never `None`.

```
    def build_collection_predicate_chain(
        self,
        model: ChatOpenAI,
        table_summarization: str,
        all_keywords: Dict[str, List[str]],
    ):
        """
        Returns list of filters like this: [{{"metadata.path_segment_X": "VALUE"}}]
        """
        all_keywords_string: str = json.dumps(all_keywords)
        path_segment_keyword_chain = (
>           {
                "PathSegmentValues": RunnableLambda(lambda x: all_keywords_string),
                "UserInformationSummary": RunnableLambda(lambda x: table_summarization),
            }
            | PromptFactory.build_collection_vector_find_prompt_v2()
            | model
            | StrOutputParser()
            | RunnableLambda(PromptFactory.clean_string_v2)
        )
E       TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'NoneType'

../ChainFactory.py:194: TypeError
```

My prompt template looks fine AFAICT:

```
def build_collection_vector_find_prompt_v2() -> PromptTemplate:
    prompt = (
        get_helpful_assistant_prefix()
        + """ Based on the provided summary

        Generate a JSON object containing one or more of the following keys: seg_1, 
        seg_2, seg_3, seg_4, seg_5, . . . 

        Return ONLY this list of JSON objects."""
        + """
        PATH SEGMENT VALUES:

        {PathSegmentValues}

        USER INFORMATION SUMMARY:

        {UserInformationSummary}
        """
    )
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the return statement at the end of your PromptTemplate build method. Additionally, you can't just return a string, though it looks like you know that from your type hint.  Add this to the end of the method:

`return PromptTemplate.from_template(prompt)`

The intuition here from the error was that the | operator is overloaded in LCEL, so if you see an error about an operation involving |, it most likely involves an operation with a `RunnableSerializable` like your PromptTemplate.